# Excel UserForm Add Item to Listbox and Mark As Selected

Tags: excel, listbox

While populating a ListBox, how do you mark an item as selected?

```
For Ctr = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

If LB1 = MyArray(Ctr) Then
    UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem MyArray(Ctr)   'Add item and mark as selected
Else
    UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem MyArray(Ctr)   'Just add item
End If

Next
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add a new item to a `ListBox` without specifying the optional `varIndex` parameter to `AddItem`, then it gets added to the end of the list. The index of that item is `ListCount - 1` (the `ListBox` item indices are 0-based). Therefore, in order to select it after you add it, you need to do:

```
UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(UserForm1.ListBox1.ListCount - 1) = True
```

Comment: Thanks dkikay! Sorry for the late response and for putting me on the right path. Below is what I came up with.

Answer (score 0):

```
' FROM MY UserForm_Initialize() SUB

Dim LB1 As String
 LB1 = Cells(RW, 8) 'DATA FROM COLUMN 8 IN THE SELECTED ROW PUT IN THE VARIABLE LB1
PopulateListBox (LB1)

'THE FUNCTION CALLED
 Private Function PopulateListBox(ByVal LB1)
'MsgBox LB1

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim Ctr As Integer
Dim i As Integer

MyArray = Array("Yes", "No")
For Ctr = LBound(MyArray) To UBound(MyArray)

'IF LB1 MATCHES THE ARRAY ITEM, TAKE THAT ITEMS KEY (Ctr) AND PUT IN VARIABLE i

If LB1 = MyArray(Ctr) Then
    UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem MyArray(Ctr)
    i = Ctr
    'MsgBox i
Else
    UserForm1.ListBox1.AddItem MyArray(Ctr)
End If
 Next
 'SHOW SELECTED LISTBOX ITEM BY ADDING i AS THE SELECTED LISTBOX ITEM'S KEY
 UserForm1.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True
End Function
```